# Protecting/limiting my API endpoints to server side use

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mean-stack

I am new to Node and web development. I am working on a simple application to get started and want to limit the use of my endpoints to server side calls, i.e. anyone else trying to access them gets a 403.

However, after researching, I found PassportJS with examples of how to protect endpoints, but they all seem to be overkill especially for a small application like mine.

Am I overthinking this, or should I be looking for a more basic solution?

Comment: If all you want to enable is server-to-server communication and you control both servers, then you can use a simple secret (e.g. a password) and SSL.  The password can be used initially and then turned into a login cookie which is used for subsequent communication or the credential can be included as a header or query parameter on all requests.  SSL is used to protect the password from snooping.

Answer (score 0):

How do you need to consume these end points yourself? I don't know if all you are looking to do is to call one file from the other. You need not expose them as restful end points in that case. Create the methods as module methods (as in node modules). Then just use require syntax to reference that file as a dependency.

You need restful end points for server side only if it needs to be called from another web application.